# What is difference between 'the world' and 'a world'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference, sentence-structure

In this following context, how is different between ''the world'' and ''a world''?

Should I take ''a world of'' as the figurative meaning: ''a very great deal of''?

The context:

> An eternally surging sea of feelings, perceptions, volitions and
> states of consciousness: such is existence, such is Samsara, the world
> of arising and passing away, of growing and decaying, **a world**
> of sorrow, misery, lamentation and despair.

Source:
Page.7
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "a world of X" means "an unimaginably huge amount of X".

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/world) has this definition:

> **11 :** an indefinite multitude or a great quantity or distance
> *// makes a world of difference
>
> // a world away*

It's metaphorical, as if the amount of X is comparable to the size of the whole world. It's usually used with overwhelming amounts.

Here are some more examples:

> Your help after Jim died made a world of difference to me, and I can't thank you enough.
> There's a world of opportunity in data analysis these days.
> You're entering a world of pain.

Answer (score 0):

> The definite article (the) is used before a noun to indicate that the identity of the noun is known to the reader. The indefinite article (a, an) is used before a noun that is general or when its identity is not known. [Source](http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/articles.html)

So "a world" shows how the "world" they are describing is "known". So it seems this text "creates" a world, before re-describring another world but with the complete opposite "emotions" in play.

Comment: Please a little more explain. I'm not clear enough yet. @DialFrost.